# Why native Quarkus executable does not launch my Jax-rs resources with maven multimodule structure?

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to develop a quarkus application with a Hexagonal architecture.

Application code is available in [github](https://github.com/BaptisteMeynier/Quarkus-Portfolio).

I have 4 modules; Business, Persistence, Webservice and the application is packaged in a global module where I will produce my Quarkus application.

When I launch:

```
mvn clean package -Pnative
```

and then my native image

```
portfolio-app/target/portfolio-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

Quarkus is not able to expose my PortfolioEndpoint which is not in the main module.

I could put my endpoint in my portfolio-app and it's work, but I don't want to break the hexagonal architecture.

Should I have put all my Quarkus features in the same maven module or is it possible to split features in multiple package ?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me, would you like to open an issue please?

Comment: Thx @geoand I created the issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1728

Comment: @geoand I'm not sure if is it exactly the same issue, but when I try to inject bean in my quarkus main app (the implementation coming from an other maven module). I get an error when I process construction of native image. Arc doesnot find default implementation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the same issue. It seems like the indexing process is not happening at all for the dependencies and therefore nothing works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to correct the issue adding [jandex maven plugin](https://github.com/wildfly/jandex-maven-plugin) in my parent pom following advice of @gsmet

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-index</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jandex</goal>
                </goals>
                <!-- phase is 'process-classes by default' -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Nothing needed here for simple cases -->
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The plugin will generate a file which is called jandex.idx containing reference to all .class files contained in target/classes folder.

```
└── target
├── classes
│   ├── META-INF
│   │   └── jandex.idx <==== here
│   └── org
│       └── acme
│           └── quarkus
│               └── portfolio
│                   └── persistence
│                       └── repository
│                           ├── SqlRepositoryAdapter.class
│                           └── SqlRepositoryProvider.class
```